# Saving multiple plots in png format

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```
dictionary=pd.DataFrame({"State":[1,4,3,6,2,4,9],"Economy":[45,32,45,12,34,56,45]})
```

I run a for loop to visualize the data. It makes two charts for each State and Economy.

```
for i in dictionary.keys():
    pd.DataFrame(dictionary[i]).plot()
    plt.savefig('all.png')
```

The `plt.savefig` creates a picture only of the last (second) chart. How can I save both charts as png or other format images. Even if I remove the indent before `plt.savefig('all.png')` it still doesn't work.

Comment: aren't you just saving over the same file multiple times? you need to change the name of the image for every iteration

Comment: maybe I do :), this makes sense. WAs not aware

Comment: Like this: `plt.savefig(f"plot_{i}.png")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can u expect 2 figures with the same name under the same directory?

```
dictionary=pd.DataFrame({"State":[1,4,3,6,2,4,9],"Economy":[45,32,45,12,34,56,45]})
for i in dictionary.keys():
    pd.DataFrame(dictionary[i]).plot()
    plt.savefig('all_{}.png'.format(i))
```